# UIkit.uploadDrop is not a function (typescript)

Tags: typescript, uikit, next.js

I am using @types/uikit npm package and am running into this error. This is my code right now

```
    UIkit.uploadDrop('.js-upload', {
    action: '',
    single: true,
  } as UIkit.UploadOptions);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using 'next/head' and including this as a separate JS file like `upload.js` on your page?

For example, you can load external files for specific pages this way:

```
 import React from "react"
  import Head from 'next/head'
  import MyAwesomeComponent from "../components/mycomponent.js"
  export default () => (
    <div>
      <Head>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/chatwidget.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/download.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin@3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/scripts/chatHead.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/libs/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
      </Head>

      <MyAwesomeComponent /> {/* a simple React component that returns  : <p>Hello World </p>*/}
    </div>
  )
```

You could then, using this approach, include your upload.js file, with code from UIKit library, to handle the uploads, this way. The reason I suggest this approach is because I spent many hours stuck trying to battle against UIkit Typescript typings and not being able to move beyond that even though the code for the component itself was correct. Was I moved my snippet to handle the upload using the method above, it all worked just fine, out of the box.

You can move this new js file into your static directory, which after Next 8.0+ is called `public`.

I know this doesn't address the error specifically, but it might give you a different approach to try.